# Why do my kernel packages contain the name of a different ubuntu version?

Tags: ubuntu, software-update

I run Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) on my desktop at work. I cannot upgrade because subsequent distributions of Ubuntu are incompatible with my lab's robot.

In the latest set of security updates, I noticed, confusingly, that certain packages contain the name "xenial", which is the name of Ubuntu 16.04.

The packages that confuse me are:

- linux-generic-lts-xenial
- linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial
- linux-image-generic-lts-xenial

After some investigation, I determined that these packages are already installed on my system.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux | grep xenial | cut -d ' ' --fields=3
linux-generic-lts-xenial
linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial
linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
```

Reading the description field of `dpkg -l`, I found the following descriptions:

```
linux-generic-lts-xenial           Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial   Generic Linux kernel headers
linux-image-generic-lts-xenial     Generic Linux kernel image
```

However, running `lsb_release` assures me that I am indeed running Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)

```
$ lsb_release -rcd
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I have a couple questions that directly follow from these observations:

1. Why do the kernel packages installed on my trusty desktop have "xenial" in their names? Does this mean that I'm running a kernel associated with xenial and not with trusty?
2. What is the difference between running the xenial version of Ubuntu and having xenial kernel packages?

And a tangential question:

3. The xenial packages made me worry that I would accidentally upgrade my version of Ubuntu. Will Ubuntu ever upgrade its version (e.g. through Software Updater's security updates) without having me explicitly confirm that the version is being upgraded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have the `xenial` kernel (v4.4) because of an Ubuntu optional feature called [**Hardware Enablement Stack**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) (also known as **HWE** or **LTS enablement stack**).

   On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, if you freshly installed with Ubuntu 14.04.2 or newer, you're automatically enrolled in HWE.  Ubuntu 14.04.1 or Ubuntu 14.04 by default remain on the `trusty` kernel (v3.13).

   You can see the Ubuntu 14.04 kernel support schedule here (click image to expand):

   [image: Ubuntu 14.04 Kernel Support Schedule]

   2. HWE just gives you the kernel and graphics support from the latest release of Ubuntu, up to the next LTS.  In your case, you'd have the `xenial` kernel and graphics packages, but everything else (should) still be built for `trusty`.
   3. [Unlike Microsoft Windows](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3030564/microsoft-windows/microsoft-uses-the-force-you-will-upgrade-to-windows-10.html), Ubuntu will *not* force you to upgrade your release.  Ubuntu would notify you of new releases that you can optionally choose to install on your own time, but you can [disable the notifications if you want](https://askubuntu.com/a/115914/18979).

      Note that Ubuntu releases do reach "end of life" on a schedule, which you can [learn about more in detail here](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life).

Comment: Thanks @Deltik, this answer is really helpful! Follow-up question: Why are the three aforementioned kernel packages held back when I do `sudo apt-get upgrade`? Is there an `apt-get` command that will update them?

Comment: @dinosaur: This is answered in [“The following packages have been kept back:” Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/601/18979) on Ask Ubuntu.